# Why the /etc/nshadow file remains after changing root password?

Tags: linux, password, shadow

I saw some abnormal thing after changing root password in linux. When I typed `ls -al /etc/ | grep shadow` after changing root password, the result is as below.

```
-r--------  1 root root   653 Mar  9  2018 gshadow
-r--------  1 root root   800 Jul 25 06:43 shadow
-r--------  1 root root   796 Jul 25 06:43 shadow-
```

But sometimes the result is different with the above.

```
-r--------  1 root root   653 Mar  9  2018 gshadow
-r--------  1 root root   ?   Jul 25 06:43 nshadow
-r--------  1 root root   ?   Jul 25 06:43 shadow
-r--------  1 root root   ?   Jul 25 06:43 shadow-
```

I'm just showing an example and don't remember exact size of those files (nshadow, shadow, shadow-).

As my research, the `/etc/nshadow` is written by passwd when changing password, and then passwd just renames `/etc/nshadow` to `/etc/shadow`. But I don't know it is correct.

Anyway, what is the `/etc/nshadow`?? and why this file is generated?? Please let me know the reason :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `passwd` command first writes the modified contents of the `/etc/shadow` file in full to `/etc/nshadow`, runs `fsync()` to ensure the nshadow file is actually written to the disk, and then renames `/etc/nshadow` to `/etc/shadow`.

This is done to eliminate the possibility of ever having an incomplete file in place as `/etc/shadow`, even for the briefest time. POSIX specifications say that file rename operations within a single filesystem must be *atomic*, i.e. any other operations must only be able to see the rename operation as either "not started yet" or "fully completed", never in any kind of "in progress" half-way state.

The `pwconv` command will also produce `/etc/npasswd` and `/etc/nshadow` when you use it to convert an archaic non-shadowed password file to the shadowed format. Some versions of `pwconv` may require the system administrator to move those files into place manually.

If `/etc/nshadow` exists on your system, it might be a remnant of a `pwconv` command run at some time in the past... or it might be there because the `rename("/etc/nshadow", "/etc/shadow")` system call at the end of some password change operation failed. Such a failure would suggest possible filesystem corruption, or other problems.

If the timestamp of the `nshadow` file is `Jul 25 06:43`, then you might want to find out what happened on the system at that time. Was there a problem of some sort that has since then been fixed, or did someone run the `pwconv` command for any reason?

If the root password was changed using some sort of automation tool, you might want to find out exactly what that automation tool will actually do. Perhaps it will run `pwconv` for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful to me :). The change of the root password in my system is triggered by uart command from others. After receiving command, my system use `echo -e "password\npassword" | passwd root` command to change root password. When I use this command, is the pwconv also used??

Comment: Also, if all three files related shadow (nshadow, shadow, shadow-) are remaining, can I understand as below??
`nshadow : the file saved a new password` / `shadow : the file saved an original password` / `shadow- : the backup file of shadow`

Comment: No, it shouldn't use `pwconv`. If `/etc/nshadow`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/shadow-` all have the same timestamp, it suggests something caused at least two successful password changes within the same minute, and possibly failed a third change attempt. And your method means the root password is stored unencrypted **somewhere**, which is generally not a good idea. There is a `chpasswd` command which accepts `username:password` pairs (one per line) from standard input; that would be a better choice for automated password changes. With the `-e` option it can accept encrypted passwords.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :). But I'm confused why the `/etc/nshadow` is generated again when I change root password.

I removed `/etc/nshadow` so that only remains `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/shadow-` before test. After I change the root password to another using `echo -e "password\npassword" | passwd root`, `/etc/nshadow` is generated and only `/etc/shadow` is updated and `/etc/shadow-` is not updated. I'm so confusing :(

Comment: If you run `type passwd`, it will tell you where the actual command is located; does it say `/usr/bin/passwd` or something else? You might also use `rpm -qf $(which passwd)` to find out the name and version of the RPM package the command comes from, if your distribution is RPM-based. For `.deb`-based distributions, the equivalent command would be `dpkg-query -S $(which passwd)`. With the name of the Linux distribution and the name & version of the package, it might be possible to find out if it's a known bug/quirk, or something else.

Comment: the `passwd` is located `/usr/bin/passwd`.
When I typed `rpm -qf $(which passwd)`, the result was `rpm: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
Also, the OS is based on ubuntu14.04. I hope it's helpful..

Comment: Ubuntu uses `.deb` packages instead of `.rpm`, so please try `dpkg-query -s passwd | grep Version` and `sudo dpkg -V passwd && echo OK`. But if it's "based on" an OS version released in 2014, it's probably not going to be exactly up to date anyway: Ubuntu's standard support for the version 14.04 LTS ended in April 2019. The final "end of life" is scheduled for April 2022, but that's applicable only if you pay Ubuntu for Extended Security Maintenance.

Comment: The `dpkg` command is not available. It needs to be approached from other aspect.. How about the existence of `/etc/.pwd.lock`?? Is it related to this phenomenon??
I saw the `/etc/.pwd.lock` file is generated by `lckpwdf` and then removed by `ulckpwdf`, but I don't know why the file is remaining after changing root passoword.

Comment: The result of `dpkg-query -s passwd | grep Version` is as following.
`Version: 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9.5`

Comment: This behavior is known and has been reported as a bug before, [see Ubuntu bug report #1252292](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1252292). See also the comments in [corresponding RedHat bug report.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=428337) Basically, the "lock" is not the presence of the `.pwd.lock` file itself, but the existence of a process holding onto that file. Removing the file is optional.